# Filter between two lists Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am working in an exercise where the only solution I could think of is by using a list to filter another one.

The exercise is the following:

> Using composition `(.)`, `sum`,`map` and `filter` define a function `walletValue :: [(String,Double)] -> [(String,Double)] -> Double` that given a wallet of values (represented as a list of pairs with the name of the title and it's amount) calculate it's value for a given quote (represented as a list of pairs with the name of the title and it's values).
> For example:

```
quote= [("apple", 116), ("intel", 35), ("google", 824), ("nvidia", 67)]

>walletValue [("intel", 1), ("nvidia", 1)] quote
102.0

>walletValue [("intel", 3), ("nvidia", 2)] quote
239.0

>walletValue [("intel", 3), ("facebook", 4), ("nvidia", 2)] quote
239.0
```

I found a solution but without achiving composition with `map` and `filter`.
My solution:

```
walletValue:: [(String,Double)] -> [(String,Double)] -> Double
walletValue xs ys = sum.concat.(map (\(k,v)-> map (v*) (searchC k ys))) xs


searchC :: Eq a => a -> [(a,b)] -> [b]
searchC k xs = [ v | (k,v) <- xs,k==k']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `searchC` acts as a filter, but you did not write it as a filter. Indeed, you can rewrite the logic:

```
searchC :: Eq a => a -> [(a,b)] -> [b]
searchC k xs = [ v | (k,v) <- xs,k==k']
```

to a combination of map and filter by using two patterns.

The first one is that we can rewrite:

```
[x | x <- xs, f x]
```

to:

```
filter (\x -> f x) xs
```

and the second that if the head of the list comprehension is not a variable `x`, as is here the case by rewriting:

```
[ f x | x <- xs ]
```

to:

```
map (\x -> f x) xs
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do not actually understand what is f, so I am a bit confused on how to apply the funcion composition between them.

Comment: `f` is an arbitrary function, so in this case the filter is `k == k'` with `k` as variable, so you will need to map the `(k, v)` on `k == k'`.

Comment: @Metiwi `(k,v) <- xs` is nice and elegant, but for this task you should shift to `x <- xs` where `x` the the whole pair. You can access its components using `fst x` and `snd x`. Try rewriting your code into that form first, even if it's less elegant.